# What does `int (*)(int)` in c mean with regard to type?

Tags: c, function, types

I have this C code (inspired by a test)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo (int n)
{
    static int s = 0;
    return s += n;
}

int main()
{
    int y;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        y= foo(i);
    }

    printf("%d\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

and I am specifically interested in the value of `foo` and what type it has. The compiler gives me this warning

```
test.c:18:16: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'int (*)(int)' [-Wformat]
```

but I'm not really sure what that means. What is an `int (*)(int)` and how does calling the function name with no arguments give me something of this type?

Comment: if you want to get the value of `foo`, use `printf("%p", (void*)foo);`, but it's not guaranteed by the standard. For the type, see [this](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*foo%29%28int%29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the function call, `foo` evaluates to a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`. That is the long description of `int (*)(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `foo`. To call `foo`, place `(argument)` after the name. As it is, you take the *address* of `foo`, which is of type `int (*)(int)` (pointer to function taking one integer argument and returning an int) and send it to `printf`.

`printf` then complains because you are trying to tell it to print an `int`, but are giving it a function pointer.